# Notation for Maximum function of several variables

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $u_1,u_2,\cdots,u_n\in \mathbb{R}$. Can we write a continuous notation for $$\mbox{max}(u_1,\cdots,u_n)$$
What I mean by notation is this:

I know for non negative $u_1,\cdots,u_n$ we have $\mbox{max}(u_1,\cdots,u_n)=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[k]{u_1^k,\cdots,u_n^k}$. But what if we have negative as well as positive $u_i$? I thought of using this definition recursively:
$$\mbox{max}\{a,b\}=\frac{a+b+|a-b|}{2}$$
But for large $n$ we will have a very cumbersome situation. The reason I am calling it cumbersome is because after defining a continuous definition, I have to take it's derivative (of course with some regularization parameter).

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

$h\log\left(e^\dfrac{a}{h}+e^\dfrac{b}{h}\right)\rightarrow \mbox{max}\{a,b\}$, as $h\rightarrow0$.

Proof: If $a>b$, $$h\log\left(e^\dfrac{a}{h}+e^\dfrac{b}{h}\right)=h\log\left(e^\dfrac{a}{h}\left(1+e^\dfrac{b-a}{h}\right)\right)=h\log e^\dfrac{a}{h}+h\log\left(1+e^\dfrac{b-a}{h}\right)=a+h\log\left(1+e^\dfrac{b-a}{h}\right)\rightarrow a=\mbox{max}\{a,b\}.$$
Similarly for $a<b$.

If a=b, $$h\log\left(2e^\dfrac{a}{h}\right)=a+h\log2 \rightarrow a.$$

Comment: The OP wants to take derivatives, so your formulation would require interchangeability of taking limits and differentiation, which may not necessarily hold.

Comment: I think so this is incorrect. Can you provide a proof of the same?